# Mgento what is this code doing?

Tags: magento2, php

return $result ?: [];
what is the explanation of this code in details please.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972516/best-way-to-give-a-variable-a-default-value-simulate-perl

Answer (score 1):

The explanation to this code is really simple. But to understand it, you have to know about ternary operator first. Check the below example.

`(condition) ? (if true, do this) : (otherwise, do this)`

In your statement `return $result ?: [];`

`$result` is your condition which is either true or false (in this case return is checking if $result returns something or not)

If $result returns true (meaning it has a value) then do nothing because there is no condition after `?` as you can see in `return $result ?: [];`

But if $result returns false (meaning it don't have any value) then assign an empty array [] to it which is shown by the `do this section` after the `:`

In conclusion, if the $result has a value then that value is being returned but if it does not have any value then an empty array will be returned. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is the Ternary Operator,
this code check $result having the value or not,if it has value return $result Else return empty array.